# Can you disenchant cards you obtain from Blackrock Mountain or Naxxramas?

Tags: hearthstone

I was thinking about buying one of the expansion packs and was just wondering if I could DE cards for dust. Still a little new to the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read all about disenchanting [here](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Disenchanting).
From that page:

"Only cards from the Expert [now Classic] set, non-golden versions of cards from the Promotion set, and golden versions of cards from the Naxxramas set can be crafted and disenchanted. Other cards, such as Basic and Reward cards, are considered soulbound and cannot be crafted or disenchanted."

GvG cards work the same as Classic cards, and Blackrock cards work the same as Naxxramas cards.

Comment: I think the Expert set was renamed to 'Classic'.

Comment: Although you can disenchant golden versions of adventure sets (Naxxramas and Blackrock Mountain), you can only get them by enchanting them, so you've made a mistake if you are disenchanting.

Comment: An update to this, with the new "Standard" mode coming in spring 2016, you will be able to dis/enchant cards from the advemtures not introduced within the past calendar year. See [a new way to play](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/19995505/a-new-way-to-play-2-2-2016) (hearthstone blog)

Answer (score 3):

Previously you couldn't disenchant cards from Adventures you've bought, but after patch [4.2.0.12051](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/20054739/hearthstone-patch-notes-42012051-3-14-2016) you can disenchant **and** craft the ones you've unlocked. This change isn't documented in the Patch notes, but it was [confirmed](https://twitter.com/ywoo_dev/status/710470583322935296) by a Hearthstone staff member as intentional.

Comment: Not quite right: you can disenchant any adventure card since the last patch.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, I'll fix the answer, thanks

Answer (score -1):

"Soulbound" cards cannot be crafted; this includes non-golden cards from Naxxramas and Blackrock. Here is a table:

```
|                        | Non-Golden                          | Golden                                           |
| ---------------------- | ----------------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------ |
| Basic Set              | Soulbound (obtain automatically)    | Soulbound (obtain by leveling up)                |
| Classic (Expert) / GvG | Craftable (or obtain in a pack)     | Craftable (or obtain in a pack)                  |
| Naxxramus / Blackrock  | Soulbound (obtain in the adventure) | Craftable (once you have the non-golden version) |
| Promotional            | Craftable (in some cases)           | Soulbound (obtain as promotion)                  |
| Reward                 | Soulbound (obtain as reward)        | Soulbound (obtain as reward)                     |
```

I have confirmed most of the above in the game, except for some of the details on promotional cards.

To craft a golden Naxxramas or Blackrock card, you go to crafting mode and click on "Show Only Golden Cards". This won't work for cards you don't already own. However, you don't need the non-golden versions of classic or GvG cards to craft the golden ones.